# android cannot set fragment from variable

Tags: android, variables, fragment

I have a some problem. My phone shows a black screen when I'm trying to add object of my fragment to FragmentTransaction:

```
LoginFragment lf = new LoginFragment();
fTrans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fTrans.add(R.id.loginContainer, lf).commit();
```

But if I add to FragmentTransaction like this, it's alright

```
fTrans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fTrans.add(R.id.loginContainer,
    new LoginFragment()).commit();
```

And so I use lg optimus l7(android version 4.0.3), on another versions(4.2.2 and higher) it's working good.
Anyone did face with this problem?